# Calling a Handler Function inside Resolver Function of GraphQL

Tags: function, http, go, graphql

I am using Go and GraphQL.

I have a Function for Signing in (SignIn) to a website.
I want to call this function inside the Reslover function of GraphQL but i am not able to pass the 'ResponseWriter' and 'Request' arguments to the function.

```
var Connect2QB = &graphql.Field{
    Type: graphqll.UniversalType,
    Resolve: func(params graphql.ResolveParams) (interface{}, error) {

        SignIn()
        return nil, nil
    },
} 

func SignIn(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Println("inside signIn")
    ...
    ...
    ... // Rest of the code
}
```

The problem i am facing is that, the function SignIn() takes two arguments. How should i pass it in the resolver function??

Comment: Are you using this package https://github.com/graphql-go/graphql

Comment: Yes. I am using github.com/graphql-go/graphql